# A certain “harmonic” sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a simple, elementary proof of the fact that:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{6n+1}+\frac{-1}{6n+2}+\frac{-2}{6n+3}+\frac{-1}{6n+4}+\frac{1}{6n+5}+\frac{2}{6n+6}\right)=0$$
I have thought of a very simple notation for "harmonic" sums like these: just write down the numerators. So, for example:
$[\overline{1}]=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots=\infty\;$ is the harmonic series
$[\overline{1,-1}]=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots=\ln2\;$ is well known
$[\overline{1,1,-2}]=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{-2}{3}+\dots=\ln3\;$ is slightly less well known (I think)
$[\overline{1,0,-1,0}]=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{0}{2}+\frac{-1}{3}+\dots=\frac{\pi}{4}\;$ is the Gregory-Leibniz series for $\pi$

What I claim is that $[\overline{1,-1,-2,-1,1,2}]$ is equal to $0$. I wonder if there are any simple proofs of this (i.e. definitely without using calculus, preferably without appealing to complex numbers/taylor series/etc.)

P.S. I know a method that doesn't use any integrals or derivatives, but requires knowledge of the taylor series for $\ln(x)$ and the Euler formula for $e^{ix}$.

The reason I believe that there should be an elementary proof is that the sum, $0$, is a very simple number.

Comment: I believe all of those "well known" harmonic-like sums have been proven using calculus. If so, then why do you expect there to be a non-calculus solution to evaluate this sum?

Comment: Because the answer is 0. I feel that such a simple answer deserves a simple proof.

Comment: There is, I"m typing it up right now.

Comment: ^Ahh, very well done.

Comment: Your series is equal to the Dirichlet series for MangoldtLambda[6]=0  joriki answered that here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/51708/8530 and said that Abels theorem would be needed to make the proof rigourous.

Comment: @MatsGranvik This series is actually $\ln2+\ln3-\ln6$ using the series from my other post.

Comment: A related matrix: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hamjh.jpg

Comment: The overbar notation may be also found in http://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/digits.pdf and this series, as well as some others, in https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Jaume_Oliver_Lafont/Zero_relations.

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont Nice. (I'm willing to bet that all of the identities in your OEIS page have simple proofs similar to the accepted answer below.)

Comment: Would $2log(3)-log(9)=0$ have a such a proof knowing only $log(2)$?

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont I'm not sure what you mean, but note that the accepted answer below doesn't even need you to know the series for $\ln2$. (It only requires you to recognize that two series are the same when written out.)

Comment: $$2log(3)-log(9)=2\overline{[1,1,-2]}-\overline{[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-8]}$$ $$=\overline{[2,2,-4,2,2,-4,2,2,-4]}+\overline{[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-8]}$$ $$=\overline{[1,1,-5,1,1,-5,1,1,4]}$$, but this is $$\overline{[1,1,-2,1,1,-2,1,1,-2]}-3\overline{[0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,-2]}$$ so it is also the same series... Maybe $log(2)+log(3)+log(5)-log(30)$ is not as easy to break into two components because there are three independent factors.

Comment: Adding the shortest zero relation to Leibniz series slightly improves its convergence http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1639961/134791

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We may rewrite your series in the following manner:

\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{6n+1}+\frac{-1}{6n+2}+\frac{-2}{6n+3}+\frac{-1}{6n+4}+\frac{1}{6n+5}+\frac{2}{6n+6}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{6n+1}+\frac{-1}{6n+2}+\frac{1}{6n+3}+\frac{-1}{6n+4}+\frac{1}{6n+5}+\frac{-1}{6n+6}\right)\\
&\hspace{1cm}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{3}{6n+3}-\frac{3}{6n+6}\right)\\
\end{align}
But these summations are *both* the alternating series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n+1}$. Therefore they cancel and the summation is equal to zero.

Comment: Ah. I wonder why I didn't notice that before! Good job.

Comment: Good answer. $\log(2)-\log(2)=0$

Comment: Looking at this again: We could also do a "$\log(3)-\log(3)$" proof, using the series for $\log(3)$ given in the question. In the notation introduced there:$$[\overline{1,-1,-2,-1,1,2}]=[\overline{1,1,-2,1,1,-2}]-[\overline{0,2,0,2,0,-4}],$$which equals $[\overline{1,1,-2}]-[\overline{1,1,-2}]=0$.

Answer (score 4):

In the language of Dirichlet series and the Riemann zeta function I believe this could be counted as an elementary proof:

Add the variable $s$ as an exponent to your series so that it becomes:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(6n+1)^s}+\frac{-1}{(6n+2)^s}+\frac{-2}{(6n+3)^s}+\frac{-1}{(6n+4)^s}+\frac{1}{(6n+5)^s}+\frac{2}{(6n+6)^s}\right)$$

$$=\zeta(s)\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^{s-1}}\right)
$$

In the case of $s=1$ we have exactly your series.

Therefore we investigate the limit:

$$\lim_{s\to 1} \, \zeta(s)\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^{s-1}}\right)$$

taking only parts of the limit we have:

$$\lim_{s\to 1} \, \zeta(s)\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}\right)=\log(2)$$

and:

$$\lim_{s\to 1} \, \left(1-\frac{1}{3^{s-1}}\right)=0$$

therefore we have:

$$\lim_{s\to 1} \, \zeta(s)\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^{s-1}}\right)=\log(2) \cdot 0 = 0$$

hence:

$$\lim_{s\to 1} \, \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(6n+1)^s}+\frac{-1}{(6n+2)^s}+\frac{-2}{(6n+3)^s}+\frac{-1}{(6n+4)^s}+\frac{1}{(6n+5)^s}+\frac{2}{(6n+6)^s}\right)=0$$

which is equivalent to:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{6n+1}+\frac{-1}{6n+2}+\frac{-2}{6n+3}+\frac{-1}{6n+4}+\frac{1}{6n+5}+\frac{2}{6n+6}\right)=0$$

Comment: Wow. Very interesting. And I think I know how to transform this proof into @Semiclassical's; note that $\zeta(s)(1-2^{1-s})=\eta(s)$, the alternating zeta function, and then write that last limit out. This is interesting stuff.

Comment: Ok, just in case you would be interested in the alternating zeta function via matrices, I post you this link: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/547951/8530

Answer (score 2):

I think we can "squeeze" something out of this:
$$0=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{6n+6}+\frac{-1}{6n+6}+\frac{-2}{6n+6}+\frac{-1}{6n+6}+\frac{1}{6n+6}+\frac{2}{6n+6}\right)\le\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{6n+1}+\frac{-1}{6n+2}+\frac{-2}{6n+3}+\frac{-1}{6n+4}+\frac{1}{6n+5}+\frac{2}{6n+6}\right)\le\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{6n+1}+\frac{-1}{6n+1}+\frac{-2}{6n+1}+\frac{-1}{6n+1}+\frac{1}{6n+1}+\frac{2}{6n+1}\right)=0$$

Comment: Ah. Never mind. The negative terms in the sum would reverse the inequalities for those terms. This will not work.

Comment: The previous answer gets my up vote then.

Answer (score 2):

Write term $n$ in the form
$$
\left(\frac1{6n+1}+\frac1{6n+2}+\cdots+\frac1{6n+6}\right)
-\left(\frac1{3n+1}+\frac1{3n+2}+\frac1{3n+3}\right)
-\left(\frac1{2n+1}+\frac1{2n+2}\right)+\frac1{n+1}.
$$ Sum from $n=0$ to $n=N-1$. This gives the $N$th partial sum for the series:
$$\left(\sum_1^{6N}\frac1k-\sum_1^{3N}\frac1k\right)
-\left(\sum_1^{2N}\frac1k-\sum_1^N\frac1k\right)=\sum_{3N+1}^{6N}\frac1k-\sum_{N+1}^{2N}\frac1k.
$$
Let $N\to\infty$. Each sum on the RHS converges to $\log 2$, by [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4356435/215011).

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment in response to Mats Granvik's answer.

I bet Mats Granvik's Trick generalizes to all Weinberger series!

Let $$f(s,\vec{a})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{a_n}{n^s}} $$

be called a *Weinberger* series when $f(1,\vec{a})=0$

where $\vec{a}=(a_1, a_2,\dots a_p)$ and $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}, \text{ }a_{p+k}=a_{k}$.

Let $p=q_1^{e_1} \dots q_l^{e_l}$ be the prime factorization of $p$.

Conjecture $$f(1,\vec{a})=0\implies f(s,\vec{a})=\lim_{x\to s}\zeta(x)\prod_{i=1}^l(1-\frac{1}{q_i^{x-1}})^{e_i}$$

Let's consider another case. How about  $\vec{a}=[1,-3,1,1]$?

$f(\vec{a},s)=\zeta(s)(1-\frac{1}{2^{s-1}})^2$

I think generally speaking the factor-ability of $f$ may rely on the series being a Weinberger series.

By the way this would mean that $p$ prime $\implies f(1, \vec{a}) \neq 0$  and I think this is the case based on proposition 13 of this [paper](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022314X06002927/1-s2.0-S0022314X06002927-main.pdf?_tid=38ded771-f220-4104-bc89-27627174a9d7&acdnat=1534294312_9ac86ec15b98b5e9cfd4d1c8151a4fec).

Comment: If this is quickly provable/{dismissable as false} I think we should answer it here and leave it but if it turns out to be a good question then I think I should rewrite this as a new question.

Comment: I think I may have to deal with constants too. So I can just demand that $a_1=1$ and that should account for this.

Comment: Needing to know what $s$ value zeros the function obviously has to do with how function factors... The sentence above looks silly to me 24 hours later. 

The next case to consider might be $[1,1,-5,1,1,-5,1,1,4]$. You can see a picture of these functions [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aksdf22duv). But I think I might be losing a lot of accuracy due to computational constraints.

Comment: I did follow up on this thought: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2897525/characterizing-the-kernel-of-a-map-into-zeta-like-function-values?noredirect=1&lq=1