# Is this class of series all demonstrably transcendental?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, vector-spaces, transcendental-numbers, dirichlet-series

**Question:**

For a vector with integer entries $[a_0, a_1,  \dots, a_{k-1}]$ is it true that when $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{a_{n-1 \mod k}}{n}}$ is not divergent it limits to some transcendental number or zero?

**Musings:**

I will adopt something like the notation of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883233/a-certain-harmonic-sum?rq=1) post. We might call these Weinberger series. Err... I dunno we might call them something else.
Let $\vec{v}=[a_0, a_1, \dots a_k]$ be a vector with integer entries.

$ \sum{\vec{v}}=[\overline{a_0,a_1, \dots, a_{k-1}}]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{a_{n-1 \mod k}}{n}}$. I should say that I suspect that when the sum of entries of $\vec{v}$ is not zero we have that $\sum{\vec{v}}$ is divergent. All the following have that property that the sum  of entries is zero (This makes the 4th entry not ambiguous).

Let me show you a few! In this notation:

$\begin{array}{lclr}
 \\
\frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{4} & = & [\overline{1,0,1,0,-1,0,-1,0}] & \text{Why [1]}
\\
\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{9} & = & [\overline{1,-1,0}]  & \text{Don't [2]}
\\
\frac{\pi\sqrt{7}}{7} & = & [\overline{1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,0}] & \text{Hyperlinks [3]}
\\
\ln{k} & = & [\overline{1,1,\dots,1, 1-k}] & \text{Work[4]}
\\
\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi+3\ln\left(2\right)}{9}  & = & [\overline{1,0,0,-1,0,0}] & \text{In [5]}
\\
\frac{\pi+2\coth^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)}{4\sqrt{2}} & = & [\overline{1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0}] & \text{Arrays [6]}
\end{array}
$

Why [1](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ppp9ihuacf) don't [2](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/29xhfa0rdm) hyperlinks [3](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sbiccenxx5) work [4](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e68ytgdso4) in [5](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qoafwkkjgs) arrays [6](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/odk3p4keqm)?

I suspect that these are all transcendental when they are not $0$ or $\infty$. In fact! I am hoping to be able to say that they all fit neatly into some class. They all look to be $\alpha \pi+ \beta\ln(\gamma)+\delta$ for some algebraic constants $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$. But I would settle for just seeing that the guys need to be transcendental (or some clever counterexample that I am missing.) I suspect that their periodic nature should give rise to a demonstration that these are not algebraic numbers.

How can I do that?

Let me defend my use of $\vec{v}$. One should only use this notation if they are vectors is some sense. And they are. Note that we can define a type of scalar multiplication with the rationals so that

$$\frac{3}{5}\ln(2)= \frac{3}{5} [\overline{1, -1}] = [\overline{0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,-3}]$$

This is really not me saying much more than

$$ \frac{3}{5}\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3(-1)^{n+1}}{5n}$$

We have all the properties that one desires of a vector space: These values are closed under addition and have a type of multiplication with rational numbers. It leaves me wondering what the right type basis should be for this type of exploration.

Comment: I haven't worked through the proof but theorem 1 of [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S001935770180001X) implies the claim.

Answer (score 2):

Your claim seems to be essentially equivalent to the statement that the numbers  $\Psi(i/k)+\gamma$ for $i=1\ldots k-1$ and their nonzero linear combinations over the rationals are 
transcendental.  I suspect this is true, but I don't know if it can be proven.

EDIT:
[Gauss's digamma theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Gauss's_digamma_theorem)
gives a formula for $\Psi \left(i/k\right) +\gamma $ with transcendental terms.
However, I suspect that proving that the result is transcendental is beyond the current state of the art.  Perhaps it is implied by [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture).

Comment: Is this because we can use this digamma function in a type of construction of a basis for these guys? I was thinking that this might be the case after looking at the Lerch Transcendental but couldn't sort through all the details.

Comment: In effort to pin down the relationship precisely: It looks like 
$\sum [a_0,a_1,\dots a_{k-1}] =-\frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^k{a_{n-1}\Psi(\frac{n}{k})}$
 Whenever the lefthandside converges.

Comment: Which means we can use the mathematica code: a={1 ,0,0,-1,0}, Sum[(-1/Length[a])a[[n]]*PolyGamma[0,n/Length[a] ],{n,1,Length[a] }]  to evaluate these guys.

Comment: Also this seems pretty pointed related: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X06002927

Comment: In fact... my statement might just be the same as their conjecture 6.

Answer (score 0):

Extended comment:

Here is a way to "move the problem." After some elementary manipulation:

$$[a_0, a_1,  \dots, a_{k-1}]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{a_{n-1 \mod k}}{n}}=\int_{0}^1\frac{a_0x^0+a_1x+a_2x^2 +\dots+a_{k-1}x^{k-1}}{1-x^k}$$

Perhaps we can show that the righthand side is transcendental.

Comment: Also... 
$$   \gamma\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{a_n}{n}}=\int_0^\infty \bigg( \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_ne^{-x^n} \bigg) \frac{dx}{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

In this [paper](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S001935770180001X/1-s2.0-S001935770180001X-main.pdf?_tid=3aa9313e-b2a5-4cc2-a12c-f48d598ca6e4&acdnat=1533155490_c6089750c9223ecc1ccf6ce388842497) it shown that this is the case that the sum is transcendental for all prime $k$.

Notes:

Somethings to be followed upon:

1) This post can be improved by finding out what happens for non prime $k$

2) The natural generalization of this:

For a whole number $s$ and vector with integer entries $[a_0, a_1,  \dots, a_{k-1}]$ is it true that when $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{a_{n-1 \mod k}}{n^s}}$ is not divergent it limits to some transcendental number or zero? It looks to me like this is generally still undecided as [Catalan's constant's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant) algebraicity seems to undetermined (Infact we don't know if it's irrational or not).

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2881168/on-the-sets-of-sums-sum-limits-n-1-infty-fraca-nns-with-a-n-perio/2885408#2885408) can be rephrased as an answer to this question:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n} \in \mathbb{Q} \cup\mathbb{T}$.

That is, we know that it's transcendental when it's not rational.

I think we should also suspect that this value is never rational but apparently that hasn't yet proven.